# Not able to see Params attribute for the Tests in testng-results.xml

Tags: xml, report, testng

Actual problem is the parameters for the Test are not shown in the HTML Test Reports http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-reports after some debugging found out that the HTML report is generated from the XML (testng-results.xml). The XML Report auto gen by the Testng does not have the `<params>` tag for the tests which have data providers.

I am not able to see the "Params" tag in my testng-results.xml 
I checked "XMLReporter.java" which is calling a method in other XMLSuiteResultWriter.java file which tries to get the TestResults from TestContext
https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters/XMLSuiteResultWriter.java#L67 
here in the process of getting the TestResults the m_parameters is empty
Note:in the TestContext I am able to see the params for the Test but when the Mapping happens from TestContext to TestResults the parameters are not getting passed from TestContext object to the TestResults Object

Comment: I don't see anything in the TestNG documentation that indicates parameters should be included in testng-results.xml: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

Comment: Actually the Parameters of the test are not coming in the http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-reports HTML Test Report but then i debugged and found out that HTML Test Report is generated from the XML Report(testng-results.xml) which does not have <params> tag in the <test-method> .For Example Check this example https://github.com/sebarmeli/Selenium2-Java-Demo/blob/master/target/surefire-reports/testng-results.xml#L13 . Let me know if you find anything

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with the TestNG but with the version of the jMockit i am using.The Parameters are being set by Test but at the end of the Test Mockit is clearing the parameters(don't know why??) 
When i changed the version of Jmockit to 1.9 the issue was fixed and the TestNG-results.xml looks fine.